# JSONModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries -- error when key is SOMETIMES missing

Tags: youtube-api, jsonmodel

So I'm just getting started with the youtube data API and JSONModel. Using their `YouTubeBrowserDemo` as my starting point: https://github.com/JSONModel/YouTubeBrowserDemo.

So it's working fine except sometimes the MediaThumnail entry for certain videos doesn't have a `time` entry. Some returned videos have them, some don't. I'm fine with this and can of course write simple checks when I'm displaying the data, but when `arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries` is called to convert the returned JSON to my models, I get the following error and none of the JSON is converted if only one (or more) of the `time` entries are missing:

```
[JSONModel.m:205] Incoming data was invalid [MediaThumbnail initWithDictionary:]. Keys missing: {(
    time
)}
```

How do I make this conversion NOT an all-or-nothing conversion? Some kind of conditional check when mapping? Or is there a different `JSONModel` method that already does this?

---

Here's the API call and attempt to convert the resulting JSON:

```
 [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:searchURL
                                  completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err) {


                                      //got JSON back
                                      NSLog(@"Got JSON from web: %@", json);

                                      if (err) {

                                          NSLog(@"err = %@",err);



                                          [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                      message:[err localizedDescription]
                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                                            otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                                          return;
                                      }




                                      //initialize the models 
                                      // THIS IS WHERE IT SOMETIMES RETURNS OBJECTS INTO SELF.OBJECTS IF ALL THE MEDIATHUMBNAILS AHVE TIME ENTRIES, OR NOTHING IF ONE OR MORE ARE MISSING
                                      self.objects = [VideoModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:
                                                      json[@"feed"][@"entry"]
                                                      ];




                                      if (self.objects) {
                                          NSLog(@"Loaded successfully models");

                                      }
```

Here's my VideoModel.h is close to theirs - only one added property:

```
@interface VideoModel : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<VideoLink>* link;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<MediaThumbnail>* thumbnail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Author>* author;

@end
```

VideoModel.m:

```
@implementation VideoModel

+(JSONKeyMapper*)keyMapper
{
    return [[JSONKeyMapper alloc] initWithDictionary:@{
            @"media$group.media$thumbnail":@"thumbnail",
            @"title.$t": @"title"
            }];
}

@end
```

And my MediaThumnail.h:

```
@interface MediaThumbnail : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL* url;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int width;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int height;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* time;

@end
```

MediaThumnail.m:

```
@implementation MediaThumbnail

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy to make some of your model's properties optional with JSONModel - have a look for an example here (more examples about different features on the same page):

https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel#optional-properties-ie-can-be-missing-or-null

All in all what you need to do is add the <Optional> protocol to your property, like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional>* time;
```

That's it. Don't forget when using the property to check first if it's nil or has a value.

Comment: Note: all the property should be occurred in source json object, or you will get the same error message when parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Create an NSNull+JSON category and import that in the JSONModel.m or in the {ProjectName}-Prefix.pch

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSNull (JSON)

@end

#import "NSNull+JSON.h"

@implementation NSNull (JSON)

- (NSUInteger)length { return 0; }

- (NSInteger)integerValue { return 0; };

- (NSInteger)intValue { return 0; };

- (float)floatValue { return 0; };

- (NSString *)description { return @"0(NSNull)"; }

- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator { return @[]; }

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key { return nil; }

- (BOOL)boolValue { return NO; }

@end
```

I have been using that in many of my projects. I prefer to use this process so even if my server introduced any new JSON key for the API response, JSON parsing will still work without any crash or issue...