# JSONModel `arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries` returning nil

Tags: jsonmodel

I can't figure this out. I'm parsing the Glosbe dictionary API. Here's the API call (no need for a key):

http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=es&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=mujer&page=1&pretty=true

And here's the Charles parsing of the response:

[image]

I want to get the `meanings -> text`. Here's my WordModel.h:

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

#import "Meanings.h"

@interface WordModel : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Meanings>* meanings;

@end
```

And my `Meanings.h':

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@protocol Meanings @end


@interface Meanings : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* text;


@end
```

And I'm using `arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries` to initialize the model:

```
//initialize the models
                                      self.definitions = [WordModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:
                                                      json[@"tuc"]
                                                      ];
```

But I'm getting `nil` for `self.definitions`. I've tried a few things but am stuck at the moment.

---

EDIT

When I do this:

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

#import "Meanings.h"

@interface WordModel : JSONModel

//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Meanings>* meanings;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* meaningId;

@end
```

I get `meaningId` fine, so it's something with my `Meanings` object. However, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since the syntax for that is the same as the syntax I'm using to parse a YouTube JSON feed, so I'm at a loss as to what is wrong.

Comment: What you pasted is not valid JSON, can you have a look at putting in the real JSON source?

Comment: @IcanZilb I edited the question to include the API request (no key needed for a response) and a screenshot of the Charles response parsing.

Comment: The format of the JSON response seems very similar to the format of YouTube Data responses, so I structured my models based off the ones I used for that, and that you helped me with in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536241/jsonmodel-arrayofmodelsfromdictionaries-error-when-key-is-sometimes-missing).

Comment: to be honest, without trying out your code, it looks fine to me ... maybe try the method that returns an error and check if there's any error while parsing the JSON feed? http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSONModel/0.11.0/Classes/JSONModel.html#//api/name/arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:error:

Comment: + (NSMutableArray *)arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:(NSArray *)array error:(NSError **)err